# How do I prepend <%= request.getContextPath() %> to all relative URLs inside a jsp page?

Tags: jsp, url, tomcat

The subject says it all, almost. How do I automatically fix jsp pages so that relative URLs are mapped to the context path instead of the server root? That is, given for example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
```

how do I set-up things in a way that maps the css to `my-server/my-context/css/style.css` instead of `my-server/css/style.css`? Is there an automatic way of doing that, other than changing all lines like the above to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
      href="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/css/style.css" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look into the [`<BASE HREF="">`](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_base_href.asp) tag. This is an HTML tag which will mean all links on the page should start with your base URL.

For example, if you specified `<BASE HREF="http://www.example.com/prefix">` and then had `<a href="/link/1.html">` then the link should actually take you to /prefix/link/1.html. This should also work on `<LINK>` (stylesheet) tags.

Answer (score -3):

The better way is to HttpServletResponse.encodeURL() which will construct the url appropria